# Android: Decrease height animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, translate-animation

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect as the 'Pull to refresh' amimation in for example the Twitter client.

I want a view, which contains some text, to 'slide out' off the screen (top). I tried the transition animation and it works, except that the content below the view stays on the same place. I want the rest of the content to 'slide' to the top as well, as the view above moves out of the screen. I have set fillAfter to true, so the top view actually stays out of screen like it should, it's just the stuff below that view that won't slide up with it.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance,
Erik

Answer (score 2):

> I want the rest of the content to 'slide' to the top as well, as the view above moves out of the screen.

Assign the `TranslateAnimation` you use for your *above view* to your *content view(s)*.

Comment: This partially works; the problem is that the height of this view should increase to fill the whole screen. Now, there is an empty space at the bottom of the screen when the 'content view' slides up.